# Lognorm distribution fitting

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution, data-fitting

I am trying to do a lognorm distribution fit but the resulting paramter seem a bit odd. Could you please show me my mistake or explain to me if I am misinterpreting the parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

data = np.array([1050000, 1100000, 1230000, 1300000, 1450000, 1459785, 1654000, 1888000])
s, loc, scale = st.lognorm.fit(data)
#calculating the mean
lognorm_mean = st.lognorm.mean(s = s, loc = loc, scale = scale)
```

The resulting mean is: 945853602904015.8.
But this doesn't make any sense.

The mean should be:

```
data_ln = np.log(data)
ln_mean = np.mean(data_ln)
ln_std = np.std(data_ln)
mean = np.exp(ln_mean + np.power(ln_std, 2)/2)
```

Here the resulting mean is 1391226.31. This should be correct.

Can you please help me with this topic?

Best regards
Norbi

Comment: Mean of the log-normal is $\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2)$.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is what I am calculating in the second part. I don't know why I don't get the same result in the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can tune the parameters of the minimizer to get an acceptable result:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.optimize import minimize

data = np.array([1050000, 1100000, 1230000, 1300000, 
                 1450000, 1459785, 1654000, 1888000])

def opti_wrap(fun, x0, args, disp=0, **kwargs):
    return minimize(fun, x0, args=args, method='SLSQP', 
                    tol=1e-12, options={'maxiter': 1000}).x

s, loc, scale = st.lognorm.fit(data, optimizer=opti_wrap)
lognorm_mean = st.lognorm.mean(s=s, loc=loc, scale=scale)
print(lognorm_mean)  # should give 1392684.4350
```

The reason you are seeing a strange result is due to the default minimizer failing to converge on the maximum likelihood result.  This could be due to a mis-behaving cost function with so few data points (you are trying to fit 3 params but only have 8 data points...).  Note: I'm using scipy version 1.1.0.

Comment: okay Thank you. It is just strange becaus if I use "R" the maximum MLE methode works just fine for the same data set